# Suddenly got error (#10) Multi-app routing not enabled for IG account

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

my own facebook apps has two permission : pages_messaging and instagram_manage_messages (advanced access). about 1 year there is no problems but last week i got error from facebook api graph

`{"error":{"message":"(#10) Multi-app routing not enabled for IG account","type":"OAuthException","code":10,"error_subcode":2534090,"fbtrace_id":"AXbK-FP5KReNoMR_MaUVIf0"}}`

[image: my routing instagram to my own apps]

above is my routing IG ,please help me, to solve this, i have searched in developer community of meta but i haven't found any solution.